# What are the required policies for a IAM user that does a Serverless deployment to AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I was trying to do a simple deployment — no external resources at all — from a limited-role user, and spent three hours futzing with IAM, ending up granting the “limited” user the following policies:

- AWSCloudFormationFullAccess
- AWSCodeDeployRoleForLambda
- AWSLambdaFullAccess
- AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess
- IAMFullAccess

And I *still* got

> `error occurred: ApiGatewayRestApi - User: arn:aws:iam::265913673281:user/test-deploy-user is not authorized to perform: apigateway:POST on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2::/restapis (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 09dd8d6f-3160-46ee-8220-c6053dca9f02; Proxy: null).`

At that point, I gave up and used root access.

But that isn’t scaleable.  There must be a way to actually do this (and more important, some way other than trial-and-error).

(If it helps, I was trying to deploy [this example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/lambda/). It didn’t work at all — shocking I know — until I modified it as detailed [here](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-deployment-bucket).  Seriously, Amazon, does it have to be this difficult?)

**Update:**

A commenter wrote:

> Are you deploying from the terminal or code build?

The terminal.

> what does your server less.yml file look like?

The `serverless.yaml` is:

```
# serverless.yml
useDotenv: true
service: apollo-lambda
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-west-2
  deploymentBucket:
    name: mysys-deployment-bucket
    serverSideEncryption: AES256
  apiGateway:
    shouldStartNameWithService: true

functions:
  graphql:
    handler: build/graphql/lambda.graphqlHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: post
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: get
          cors: true
plugins:
  - serverless-deployment-bucket
```

> do you have your access key set up locally?

I do.

> this isn't too hard at all once you got it wired up correctly. –

You mean, it isn't too hard at all once you *have done the impossible stuff.*

Obviously, everything is easy except for the difficult parts.  Mt Everest?  Easy to get to the airport!  Brain surgery?  Shaving the patient’s head is easy, and billing the insurance is simple enough...

Comment: This is more of a `serverless-framework` issue than AWS. `serverless` executes the AWS API calls so it should be aware of all the IAM permissions that it requires. These API calls are dependent on your `serverless` config so there is no _one true list_ of IAM minimum permissions as it can very from project to project. I do wish there is a `serverless` CLI command that can list all those required IAM permissions based on your serverless config.

Comment: Are you deploying from the terminal or code build? what does your server less.yml file look like? do you have your access key set up locally? this isn't too hard at all once you got it wired up correctly.

Comment: @lopezdp answered in update.

Comment: Just attach `AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator` policy

Comment: @AtulSharma — why don’t you make an answer of your comment so I can accept it and give you credit?  Also, you probably know that “atul sharma” means “perfect comfort”.  Seems apt now...

Comment: @Malvolio funny!  I stroll through Mt. Everest every day. Im an engineer.

Comment: @lopezdp — Atul Sharma’s answer, in his comment above, makes me want to rage.  How on Earth could I have figure that out if he hadn’t just told me.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145088/cloudfront-ignoring-cache-control-header-from-s3/65145089) for another AWS problem with “wiring thing up correctly”, but one more of my own making.

Comment: @Malvolio the journey is what matters...

Comment: @lopezdp — though I usually agree with that, I have been working on this problem 30 of the last 48 hours, leaving little time for sleeping and, you know, my actual job, so much as I am enjoying myself, I would be OK with arriving.

Comment: dont be so dramatic its just work homie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atul Sharma wrote:

> Just attach AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator policy

and that totally worked.

Comment: not a good idea